# JavaScript optimization: matrix fall

Tags: javascript, optimization

I implemented this funny page:

http://www.xthema.it/misc/christmas-matrix.html

I retry to do it in three different way but every time I was not able to obtain good performance result with Firefox (I'm using version 17).

- First attempt was to create and remove div every time for every cell.
- Second attempt was to preallocate all the div cells at the beginning and change only characters and colors
- Third attempt (the current one) was to create a column div, add only new div cell at the bottom and remove the entire column at the end of the character fall.

On Chrome, Safari and IE, the results are always good, but on FF it is slow.

Any suggestion? There is someone who know about some FF weakness in accessing DOM or CSS? No one has any optimization to recommend?

Comment: We all have done something like that one time or another just for fun, mine was even more inefficient -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WcZeJ/)

Comment: Instead of doing this on dom, consider doing this in a 2D canvas

Comment: I've tried to recreate this animation using css3 animations. Still no luck with FF http://jsbin.com/avehax/4

Comment: Yes on FF it is still slow, but the idea was really good.

Comment: At the end I try using animation only for char fade. In this way it works, even on FF it is really smooth. Tnx, tnx, tnx!

Answer (score 1):

First and universal opimisation would be using [requestAnimFrame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). It should be used with every animation.

What I see in your code it's lots of dom manipulation. Especially you call createElement thousands of times calling drawFall. This is slow. Try to prepare fall right before it is drawn then just animate it changing colours and after that remove fall. (so try to minimize number of createElement calls) What's more you can use [documentFragment](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/) which can also help.

Other idea is to [implement it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/million_letters/) using WebGL which is, however, completely different story.

Comment: I try using `requestAnimFrame` but no significant improvements. However thanks for the good suggestion.

Comment: Yes I try to preallocate all the divs at the beginning but it seems that the operation `node.style.color = xxx` it is really slow.

Answer (score 1):

I've found another possible (super) fast solution:

Description:
take semi-transparent png and put it over your matrix letters so that some of them are semi-visible. Move the png around.
Difficult to describe - easy to follow quick'n'dirty implementation on attached jsfiddle.

Quick and dirt implementation: (see http://jsfiddle.net/zbHne/)

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#box{
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:2px solid;
  background: #000;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
onload = function(){
  var el = document.getElementById("test");
  el.style.position = "relative";

  var x = -700;
  function fly(){
    x += 10;
    el.style.left = x + "px";

    if(x > -100){
      x = -700;
    }
  }

  setInterval(fly, 50);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="box">
<div style="position: relative; width: 1000px; color: green">test of letterstest of letterstest of letterstest of letterstest of letters</div>
<div id="test"><div style="width: 1000px; height: 100px; background: url(layer.png); position: relative; top: -50px">invisible</div></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

You should create appropriate layer.png semi-transparent image in order this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I try using requestAnimFrame, but no significant improvements.

Using firebug profiler it seems that the slow operation is changing the color

cellEl.style.color = br;

So in this moment the only solution that I found is on FF minimize the palette

```
// BRIGHTNESS0 is the MAX brightness value
// BRIGHTNESSSTEPS is the palette size

// i : 31 = n : BRIGHTNESS0
var i = Math.floor(n * 31 / BRIGHTNESS0);
// brightness inc = BRIGHTNESS0 / BRIGHTNESSSTEPS
var inc = 31 / BRIGHTNESSSTEPS;
i = Math.floor(Math.floor(i / inc) * inc);

var brHex = '#';
if (i < 16) {
  var d = i * 16 + i;
  brHex += '0' + Number(i).toString(16) + '0';
} else {
  i -= 16
  var o = Number(i).toString(16);
  brHex += o + 'f' + o;
}

...
```

On FF I do not use 32 gradation but less, and if a color does not change I skip the `style.color` assignment.

```
var br = BRIGHTNESSTABLERGB[cell[1]];
if (cellEl.style.color != br)
  changeBrightness(cellEl,br);
```

In this way is little better. Any other suggestion?